# How to output an array from object without sorting it

Tags: jquery

I am using ajax and when I get my response (which is an object) it gives me weird output.

So, inside of the "success" method, I tried console.log(res) and this is what I have :

```
Object {new_month: "Semptember", days_calender: Object}
```

Then, I try console.log(res['days_calender']); and this is the output :

```
Object {10: "n", 11: "n", 12: "n", 13: "n", 14: "n", 15: "n", 16: "n", 17: "n", 18: "n", 19: "n", 20: "n", 21: "n", 22: "n", 23: "n", 24: "n", 25: "n", 26: "n", 27: "n", 28: "n", 29: "n", 30: "n", 01: "n", 02: "n", 03: "n", 04: "n", 05: "n"…}
```

The problem is I need to use method each() to create element and append it to a div #calender, but when I do it the first case got "10", the second one "11", and so on.

Is there any way to not get my object sorted?

```
dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res['days_calender']);
                $.each(res['days_calender'], function(key, val) {
                    updateCalender(key, val);
                });
```

my updateCalender function :

```
    function updateCalender(day, activity)
{
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    $('#calender ul').append(li);

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute('href', '/activities/'+day);
    a.innerHTML = day;
    li.appendChild(a);
}
```

EDIT:

This is what it looks like at first :

```
    Array
(
    [new_month] => September
    [days_calender] => Array
        (
            [01] => n
            [02] => n
            [03] => n
            [04] => n
            [05] => y
            [06] => y
            [07] => n
            [08] => n
            [09] => y
            [10] => n
            [11] => n
            [12] => n
            [13] => n
            [14] => n
            [15] => n
            [16] => n
            [17] => n
            [18] => n
            [19] => n
            [20] => n
            [21] => n
            [22] => n
            [23] => n
            [24] => n
            [25] => n
            [26] => n
            [27] => n
            [28] => n
            [29] => n
            [30] => n
        )

)
```

Comment: "not get my object sorted?" : this depends on the output from the ajax request. Can you give the plain output (not from that of the console)

Comment: your response array or data is sorted ! you can make response unsorted or whatever from server method and then make output !

Comment: in the plain output itself is sorted, then how do u expect that to be unsorted in the front end ??. If you are retrieving this from a database, don't use any sort function

Comment: @MatthieuBoisjoli something is wired in your consoled object that all the key value pair is having value **"n"** please see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort numerically the keys

```
var res = {'days_calender':{10: "n", 11: "n", 12: "n", 13: "n", 14: "n", 15: "n", 16: "n", 17: "n", 18: "n", 19: "n", 20: "n", 21: "n", 22: "n", 23: "n", 24: "n", 25: "n", 26: "n", 27: "n", 28: "n", 29: "n", 30: "n", 01: "n", 02: "n", 03: "n", 04: "n", 05: "n"}};

var array = $.map(res['days_calender'], function(value, index) { // convert to array of objects
    return {day:index, activity:value};
});

array.sort(function(a,b){ // sort numerically by day
    return parseInt(a.day) - parseInt(b.day);
});

$.each(array, function(key, val) {
    updateCalender(val.day, val.activity);
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p51yturj/)